# PHP simple subtraction

Tags: php, subtraction

In the script below, I'm trying to dynamically set the css width attribute on the .sidebar and .content elements by subtracting the value stored in the 'my_sidebar_width' variable from 950

I'm getting an error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected
>   T_DNUMBER

```
if(get_option('my_sidebar_width') !=='')
    $my_stringData .= 
    ".sidebar{width:".get_option('my_sidebar_width')."}
    .content{width:".950-get_option('my_sidebar_width')."}";
```

This is my first foray into calculating values in PHP. Do I need to explicitly convert the 'my_sidebar_width' variable to an integer? Perhaps more?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to put the substraction in parantheses, like this:

```
( 950-get_option("cb2_sidebar_width") )
```

Comment: That did it. Knew it had to be something simple :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try surrounding `950-get_option('cb2_sidebar_width')` with parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Typecasting can't hurt:

```
if(get_option('my_sidebar_width'))
    $my_stringData .= 
    ".sidebar{width:" . (string)get_option('my_sidebar_width') . "}
    .content{width:". (string)(950-(int)get_option('cb2_sidebar_width')) . "}";
```

Explicit is better than implicit, so while you may not need all of those typecasts, it can't do any harm :)

Comment: -1 for all the absolutely unnecessary typecasts, which bloat the code.